# “说不上好”的标准读音是什么？（What is the standard tone structure for "说不上好"？）

Tags: tones

Question：

根据《现代汉语规范词典》和《汉语大词典》，按照“说不上好”中的“不”字的意义，如果单独念该字的话，就定要念作第四声。“说不上好”中的“上”字则读作轻声。把整句读起来，由于“上”字轻声，“不”字不要因为后面有第四声的字而读作第二声。整句各字的声调按顺序就是这样：1-4-5-3。

然而，我在日常生活中听过很多次别人以“1-2-4-3”的声调结构说出这句话，而且我个人觉得这样说起来比较自然，尽管这可能是因为耳濡目染的原因。

“说不上好”的标准读音到底是什么呢？至少，你觉得哪种发音说起来较为自然？同样值得一提的是，这是要分口语和书面语的一种情况吗？谢谢。

Comment: 1-2-4-3 is the normal way. 1-4-5-3 sounds like speaking by a foreign tongue to me.

Comment: 谢谢。你觉得“说得上好”应该是“1-5-5-3”、“1-5-4-3”，还是都可以？

Comment: 1-5-4-3 is commonly used too.  -5-5- will be quite difficult to pronounce, also it sounds weird.

Comment: 可不是“5-5”经过语流音变以后就不是“5-5”了，所以发音并不难？

Comment: You can try to pronounce it that way and record it on your phone to hear it:)

Comment: as a native chinese speaker, I agree with Betty's comments.

Comment: You can hear people use the tone “1-2-4-3”, or "1-5-4-3". Both are quite common.

Answer (score 2):

慢慢说：1-2-4-3

快说：1-5-4-3

“上”字这里不读轻声啊，要轻声也是“不”字轻声

Answer (score 0):

我们一般都说  1 2 4 3，在中国没有 5 的发音

一般为了发音舒服，在《不》的下一个字的读音为4的时候才会用 2

Comment: 5 is the neutral tone.